# What is the most efficient way to check against a huge MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have a service in which users may "like" content posted by other users. Currently, the system doesn't filter out content that the user has already liked, which is undesirable behavior. I have a table called LikeRecords which stores a userID, a contentID, and a timePlaced timestamp. The idea is to use this table to filter content that a user has already liked when choosing what to display.

The thing is, I'm a MySQL amateur, and don't understand scaling and maintenance well. Even though I only have about 1,500 users, this table already has 45,000 records. I'm worried that as my service grows to tens or hundreds of thousands of users, this table will explode into millions and become slow since the filter operation would be called very frequently.

Is there a better design pattern I could use here, or a maintenance technique I should use?

EDIT: Here is the query for building the table in question:

```
CREATE TABLE `likerecords` (
 `likeID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `userID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `orderID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `timePlaced` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `special` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`likeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44775 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I would be using it to filter results in other tables, such as an "orders" table.

Comment: You mean to use the userID as the primary index, right? And that doesn't get pressured by, say, 30 million records?

Comment: if you use an index on the records it should still perform well when it's quite large.  I'm assuming the table will be joined with another table using the userID.  MySQL automatically indexes primary keys, foreign keys, and columns with a unique constraint, so you should be fine.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about size tolerance, and what to do once that threshold is met?

Comment: You may also be able to write a stored procedure to improve performance, but I'm guessing that it won't be necessary for this problem.  It would help a lot if you posted your table schemas.  You could do 'show create table foo' or 'desc foo' to give us more information.

Comment: Sure, I'll update the question.

Comment: I'm a little surprised to see no foreign key constraint on that table, one of those columns must correspond to the id of another table right?  like a content table?  Can you post the create table statement for the other table?  The one with content that would be filtered by this?

Comment: if it is joined with another table using the likeId, you don't need to add an index.  Just add a foreign key constraint, and probably 'on delete cascade' with that.  Then, in the query you do for the content, you will have to do a join with this table, and use a where statement to say that the content is not in this table for that user id.  I have to go to sleep, sorry, and good luck.

Comment: to scale can use sharding, or with newer data bases have data files that get split by index (like all records that start with 'a' or '8' in one physical file. those are advanced database options. can google them or maybe someone with more knowldge can explain here

Comment: The likeID field is not used in any other table. It's just something I put in because I read that it's good to have indexes, but don't fully understand why. The userID and orderID fields are what will be used to join other tables.